# I uninstalled Dropbox but still have .dropbox listed when I do ls -a. Why?

Tags: dropbox

I have uninstalled Dropbox from my Applications on OS X but it is still showing as .dropbox in my home directory.  Why is that please?

Comment: Since this is a question about the Dropbox sync client rather than the web interface, this question belongs on [su] or, since it's about OS X, on [apple.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing Dropbox doesn't delete its preferences/cache/etc, which is stored in ~/.dropbox. You can delete this yourself.